# Would adding a new currency symbol today be harder or easier than the addition of the euro?

Tags: unicode, fonts, character-encoding, ascii, currency

From a programming perspective, when the euro symbol was created, Extended Ascii had to accommodate it, as did Unicode and other code-page standards. Fonts and Printer languages had to add the new glyph. Accounting  and reporting software had to deal with a new formatting symbol. Exchange and Money markets had to deal with the addition of the XEU and subsequently the EUR.

If a major new currency (of the same magnitude as the euro) was "created" today, similar changes would be required.

Could such a new currency attain the same elevation as the euro? For example, is there room in the Extended Ascii tables, and would a major new currency symbol be considered worthy of occupying a spot.

Would it be easier to add a new currency symbol today than it was at the euro's birth, or did the humble € enter the IT world during a sweet spot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question as defined in the [help].

Comment: Would it perhaps be more on topic in Graphic Design?

Answer (score 4):

By extended ASCII, I'm assuming you're referring to it's inclusion in [Latin-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)? Introduction of a new `ISO/IEC 8859` character set to accommodate new currency symbols seems highly unlikely these days; Unicode is far more prevalent than it was when `Latin-9` was introduced. In terms of consideration and speed of inclusion into Unicode, that would depend on a fair number of factors, so it's hard to say.

The most recent proposed currency symbol inclusion that I'm aware of is for [bitcoin](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2015/15229-bitcoin-sign.pdf), which seems [likely to go ahead](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2015/15254.htm#145-C7). But this is going to be a fair duration of time between proposal and widespread font support. Interestingly the lack of support for the symbol has resulted in a [number of alternatives and approximations](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol). New currency symbols may result in similar workarounds -- it's hard to say, though.

Given how ubiquitous Unicode is now, and in particular usage of `UTF-8` on the web, I'd say new currency symbols have got a pretty good chance of relatively quick inclusion, but really it's font-support that will trail behind. The more important/prevalent the symbol, the more likely it is for font support to gain traction.

Answer (score 2):

> If a major new currency (of the same magnitude as the euro) was "created" today, similar changes would be required.

Unicode is deliberately designed with lots of space free for new symbols (eg U+20BE Lari Sign in Unicode 8.0). It takes a while for fonts to appear with glyphs for them, and for text processing systems to be able to categorise the characters correctly. But even without any special support, simple-layout characters like currency signs can be displayed (eg using embedded fonts) without any code changes to existing systems.

The Euro was planned at a time when Unicode support was still sporadic and incomplete enough that it was considered necessary to make the symbol available in Western 8-bit encodings (eg Windows code pages 1252–1258). This was a change to the meaning of existing code pages, which was a big load of hassle.

But Unicode is well-supported enough now that no-one would bother go back and change legacy encodings or add new ones just for a new currency symbol (even something as big as the Euro).

Comment: Indeed, I've assumed that Unicode would be easy enough, and as an interim measure, developers could use the reserved area to "add" their own interim character. But Unicode support isn't all pervasive in the financial world. For example, VBA works in the code page of the locale, so Unicode support isn't in the syntax, even though VBA can work with Unicode values.